# Will switching to React Hooks affect my app's bundle size?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-performance

I wrote my website with a mixture of React classes and functional components. Now I am considering rewriting it using React Hooks. It's critical to me to keep my compiled bundle small. Should I expect switching to Hooks to substantially increase or decrease the size of the bundle?

Comment: I'm assuming you prefer the functional (hooks) code better. imho it's a fools bet to choose the harder to read and modify code over a slight performance issue. I would bet the bundle stays a similar size. But, if a small bundle is your preference there are other ways [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) is one way to get faster page loads with a minimum of change, but there are others.

Comment: if you think my solution is correct please accept my answer

Answer (score 3):

Dont worry it doesnt really matter as both do the same work plus when you use react  hooks
your `bundle size tends to decrease` as your code gets drastically minified.
Here is a link you can check out from medium.com on the same issue: [the article link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889#:%7E:text=In%20terms%20of%20the%20implementation,than%20equivalent%20code%20using%20classes.)

- The support for react hooks does increase your size by 1.5kb but your code is less now

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept when you can the ones that solved your problem. Glad to help

Comment: if you think my answer is correct or useful kindly upvote it and if you agree that my answer is correct consider accepting it